# How to join the table based on main table column value in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following 3 tables:

**main_table:**

```
id,name,table_type
1a,sas,1
2a,saw,1
3a,sdd,2
```

**inst_table**

```
id,inst_name,rating
1a,sdsdf,3
2a,erer,4
```

**indv_table**

```
id,ind_name,rating
3a,gbgbg,3
5a,gff,4
```

How to join the subtables based on `main_table column:'table_type'`?

I.e., if `main table column: table_type = 1`, then it has to join with `table:'inst_table'` else `table:'indv_table'`

Comment: Add the expected result. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: If you try to simulate class derivation within an RDMS this will kill your performance. It's better to have a distinct table for each entity. Also, your two additional table are look-alikes. Why not join them in "main_table" in the first place?

Comment: Use Union to'stack' the inst and indv tables on top of each other. Then you will be able to join them easily

Comment: tried query is : select id,name from main_table
INNER JOIN (case main_table.table_type when 1 'inst_table' else 'indv_table') as sub_tab
on main_table.id = sub_tab.id

Comment: update your question and show your expected  result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM main_table t1
    INNER JOIN inst_table t2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID where t1.table_type=1
UNION ALL
  SELECT *
  FROM main_table T1
    INNER JOIN indv_table T3 ON T1.ID = T3.ID where t1.table_type=2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can left join both sub-tables to main_table:

```
proc sql;
select m.*, i.*, d.* 
from main_table as m 
left join inst_table as i on m.id=i.id and m.table_type = 1
left join indv_table as d on m.id=d.id and m.table_type ne 1
;
quit;
```